# Gurobi counting: set constraint to a percentage of grid values

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

we are using a grid (2 dimensional array). in every cell we calculate a double value.

is there a way to define a constraint (or objective) in gurobi
that makes sure that only 5% of all cells are allowed to be greater than a certain value?

Answer (score 1):

Counting needs (some form of) binary variables. E.g.

```
 x(i,j) ≤ threshold + δ(i,j)⋅(U(i,j)-threshold) 
 sum((i,j),δ(i,j)) ≤ 0.05*gridsize
 x(i,j) ∈ [0,U(i,j)]
 δ(i,j) ∈ {0,1}
```

Here `U(i,j)` is a bound on `x(i,j)` (your cell values). If you do not have a good idea about bounds on `x(i,j)`, you can use indicator constraints:

```
 δ(i,j) = 0 ==> x(i,j) ≤ threshold
 sum((i,j),δ(i,j)) ≤ 0.05*gridsize
 δ(i,j) ∈ {0,1}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. Do you maybe have a small code example?

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: I don't know how to calculate δ(i,j) and (U(i,j)? sum can be calculated with a GRBLinExpr?

Comment: δ is a binary variable. U is an upper bound on x you have to provide. If you don't know how to do a sum, please first study some of the Gurobi examples.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen how do we use the ==> operator in Gurobi? we currently get an temporary grb constraint for δ(i,j), but we cannot build a sum with that.